# Excel VBA - screenupdating anomaly when opening multiple workbooks

Tags: excel, vba, performance, subroutine

**Intro:**
I have a master workbook (A) and two other workbooks (B & C). The master workbook has a userform from which i do the following sequence:
Open B **->** run a macro that calls several other macros within B **->** save and close B **->** Open C **->** run a macro that calls several other macros within C **->** save and close C

**Problem:**
My problem is that `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` doesn't work properly. I don't mind the screen flickering, but the annoyance is that the code takes significantly longer to run than when it works properly.

**Code:** (comments are explained in next section)

```
Sub test()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Workbooks.Open ("H:\WorkbookA.xlsm")
'**** tried here ****
Application.Run ("'WorkbookA.xlsm'!TestA")
wbName = "H:\WorkbookA Test.xlsm"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=wbName
ActiveWorkbook.Close

'**** split ****

Workbooks.Open ("H:\WorkbookB.xlsm")
'**** tried here ****
Application.Run ("'WorkbookB.xlsm'!TestB")
wbName = "H:\WorkbookB Test.xlsm"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=wbName
ActiveWorkbook.Close

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

**I've tried:**
I've tried inserting `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` just before both of the `Application.Run` lines as shown in the code (**** tried here ****).

I've also looked thoroughly through my code and I am 100% sure that the problem is not due to `ScreenUpdating` being turned back on during runtime.

**Finally:**
I've tried splitting the sequence and running them separately as shown in the code (**** split ****). This works perfectly, which is super weird.

I've also noticed that very rarely the code works as intended, which confuses me, since i perform the exact same actions using the exact same dataset.

Any ideas or inputs are welcome :)

Comment: So, what you are saying is that the same code in the same workbook faster with `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` than with `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`?

Comment: @Vityata No if I split up the code i would insert `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` before each part of the code runs. Sorry for the misunderstanding.
It seems that if you run the code in one go workbook B works fine but when it reaches workbook C then `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` stops working properly.

Comment: @DirtyDeffy ... This could be because of any alert that pops up when you open up the workbook B. In addition with screenupdating = False can you put     Application.displayalerts = False.

Comment: Could it be that there is events in the workbooks that restore the ScreenUpdating value? For example in a Workbook_BeforeClose in Workbook A?

Comment: Have you tried including `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` in the code in Workbooks B & C?

Comment: just to be sure, you're not testing this while debugging? Because while debugging, screenupdating is often triggered  automaticaly to true

Comment: @MohitBansal Just tried to incorporate `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` - unfortunately it doesn't help.

Comment: @VincentG I have code that runs when the workbooks are opened but not when they are closed. They set `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` and then `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` after the code in the module is finished. However, all the code that runs after this sets `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` before running.

Comment: @FreeMan Yep - every code module starts off with `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` and ends with `Application.ScreenUpdating = True`. I make sure that no heavy code runs between it being set to `True` and it being set to `False` again.

Comment: @Wouter No I am not testing this while debugging. I run the code as I would normally do everytime :)

Comment: maybe you could post the code you're calling from the other workbooks. Maybe it will make some things clear

Comment: @Wouter Yeah it's not that I don't want to show you guys the code, but there's around 50 times more code than what I've already posted here, split into +10  subroutines. I doubt it will provide clarification.

Comment: If you have code running on openning it is the same problem. Instead of having code that turn ScreenUpdating Off and then On, you could read and save the previous value, and restore the previous value: `OldValue = Application.ScreenUpdating : Application.ScreenUpdating = False ....... Application.ScreenUpdating = OldValue` This way, if SceenUpdating is False before the event it will still be False after the event.

Comment: @VincentG I use several other workbooks that all turn ScreenUpdating on and off on the open event without issues. The thing is that while ScreenUpdating might be turned on by the open event, it is immediately turned off again, as soon as the macro runs. All my macros start with `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`